# Pattern to List of Patterns

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, pattern-matching

I actually have this case where I have to verify if there's an overlapping pattern (may it be regex or something else).

```
string pattern = "123*"
string[] patterns = new string[]  { "123?", "123*", "12?", "*23*" }
```

I believe from here the overlapping matches are `"123?"`, `"123*"` and `"*23*"`

Wild cards would be limited to `"*"` for any trailing characters and/or `"?"` for any 1 length

This by the way is for the purpose on number formats so there's a possibility also to include literal dashes (at most) within number patterns / formats.

Can this be accomplished with Regex or other? in C# / Javascript if possible.

Please put a comment for any info I missed.

TIA

Comment: Hello, I can't get what you are trying to achieve. Please elaborate.

Comment: I think you'll need to specify how much of the grammar you want to cover; it's doable if we limit to `?*.`, but if you get into complex lookahead and capturing groups, etc, it will be difficult to impossible.

Comment: @KenY-N hi Kenny, I think I'm limited to just numbers like 8 digit number or digit formats with dashes at most so yeah for the wild-cards and stuff I'm quiet limited to asterisk and question mark for lengths

Comment: What does `?` mean in `12?`?

Comment: @revo any 1 length character

Comment: Then I think you would better clear in your question that those symbols don't follow their definition in a regex context and define them.

Comment: @revo i just did my edit, hope it clears the question more

Comment: I think you could replace all `?` and `*` with `.` (to make it a regex) then test each pattern in list against defined single pattern.

Comment: See demo here http://jsbin.com/ceqorekoke/edit?js,console

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine 
start reading buddy

Comment: @revo hi revo, I think i'm getting a hang of it, but i'm having some issues comparing the following values, `888?-*` and `8888?8`, is there any way I could make them match? the `-` is a concrete one btw..

Comment: If you want to match these two it means `123*` and `12?` should match as well. Since latter is a part of former: `123.` and `12.`. Right?

Comment: @revo not exactly because if I want to match those 2, it's like I wish to match `12?-*` and `123?1` sorry if this one's not part of the test case..but yeah still need to accomplish this case.

Answer (score 0):

just want to share the solution I have for now, but this is via C#.

```
static string regRep(string inp)
{
    return inp.Replace("*", ".*").Replace('?', '.').Replace("-", @"\-");
}

static string regRep2(string inp)
{
    return inp.Replace("*", ".*").Replace('?', '.').Replace("-", ".");
}

static void Main()
{
    var patterns = new string[] { "8888*", "8889*", "8898*", "8899*", "8988*", "8989*", "8989*", "8999*", "7898*", "7899*", "8888?8", "888?-8", "*88*" };
    string ar = @"888?-*";

    List<string> res = new List<string>();

    bool mat1, mat2;
    Regex reg1, reg2;
    foreach (var reg in patterns)
    {
        reg1 = new Regex(regRep(reg));
        reg2 = new Regex(regRep(ar));

        mat1 = reg1.IsMatch(ar);
        mat2 = reg2.IsMatch(reg);

        // standard matching
        if (mat1 || mat2)
        {
            res.Add($"{ar} std matched with {reg}");
        }
        else
        {
            //forced matching
            reg1 = new Regex(regRep2(reg));
            reg2 = new Regex(regRep2(ar));
            mat1 = reg1.IsMatch(ar);
            mat2 = reg2.IsMatch(reg);

            if (mat1 || mat2)
            {
                res.Add($"{ar} frc matched with {reg}");
            }
        }
    }
}
//result
Count = 5
    [0]: "888?-* frc matched with 8888*"
    [1]: "888?-* frc matched with 8889*"
    [2]: "888?-* frc matched with 8888?8"
    [3]: "888?-* std matched with 888?-8"
    [4]: "888?-* std matched with *88*"
```

This one for now works for me, I hope someone will too, if not, better. thanks!